# SugarCRM undefined index 'LNK_IMPORT_ACCOUNTS'

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I've cloned a SugarCRM installation to do some development work on. The main installation is working fine. The clone, however, shows this error message on most pages:

```
Undefined index: LNK_IMPORT_ACCOUNTS in E:\sugarcrm\modules\Project\Menu.php on line 51
```

Stack trace:

```
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0002  369896  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
2   0.1949  10955048    SugarApplication->execute( )    ..\index.php:44
3   0.2216  11487864    SugarController->execute( ) ..\SugarApplication.php:85
4   0.2221  11488048    SugarController->processView( ) ..\SugarController.php:274
5   0.2363  13555528    SugarView->process( )   ..\SugarController.php:293
6   0.2394  13577848    SugarView->displayHeader( ) ..\SugarView.php:119
7   0.3088  16498752    SugarView->getMenu( string(7) ) ..\SugarView.php:559
8   0.3091  16511816    require( 'E:\sugarcrm\modules\Project\Menu.php' )   ..\SugarView.php:981
```

I'm not very familiar with how SugarCRM populates its global $mod_strings array which is expecting to have this index in it. As far as I can see the method LanguageManager::loadModuleLanguage() will load the strings from a cache file. I've verified that the cache file exists and contains this key, as well as deleted everything from the cache directory, and I still get the above error message.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look SugarCRM Developer Guide [section](http://developers.sugarcrm.com/docs/OS/6.3/-docs-Developer_Guides-Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.3.0-Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.3.0.html#9003251) related to customizing language strings, vardefs and so on using 'custom/Extension' directory. "Languages" paragraph gives complete information on adding and modifying custom language strings.

In your situation I think you should update/create file 'custom/Extension/modules/Project/Ext/Language/en_us.custom.lang.php' and add

```
$mod_strings['LNK_IMPORT_ACCOUNTS'] = 'Import Accounts';
```

to the end of the file.

Comment: Thanks. I had found some of those docs. This problem appears to be in the Project modules Menu.php expecting a string to be defined which comes from the Accounts module. In other parts of the code, including the same Menu.php file, instead of using `$mod_strings['LNK_NEW_PROJECT']` they use `isset($mod_strings['LNK_NEW_PROJECT']) ? $mod_strings['LNK_NEW_PROJECT'] : ''`. Using the same technique here gets me past the error. I guess it was there in our main installation but we never saw it because php error reporting didn't show the notice. Thanks.